# Clipping DEM / DTED data selecting by extent

Tags: qgis, dem, clip

similar to a few queries but really struggling to clip a DEM file from say USGS.

Going to Raster > Extraction > Clipper and then "select the extent by drag on canvas", does not work.

The process will continue for up to 1 hour then give error messages implying not enough storage?

I'm on QGIS 2.8 Tien, running a MacbookPro on El Capitan... didn't work prior to OS upgrade though from Yosemite.

Any ideas? Tried out thinking this and tried to clip after extracting contours, and then trying to clip by extent but this isn't possible at moment I think unless a tool is developed. My project is to Just make a file at 10km square of contours to input into Google Earth.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added a snapshot of process, any ideas?

Comment: Raster CRS and project CRS should match, i.e. on-the-fly-reprojection should be **off**.

Comment: Hi AndreJ - thanks - could you explain this a bit further please?

Comment: Hey AndreJ - simple but genius! worked. many thanks and consider this issue solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster CRS and project CRS should match, i.e. on-the-fly-reprojection should be **off** for the clipping operation.

From your screenshot, I assume you are using a raster with a cell size in degrees, while the coordinates seem to be in meters.